# How do you extract excel data using criteria from 2 columns?

Tags: excel, formula

I have two columns of raw data, one with 3,000 instances of numbers 0-100 the second with 3,000 instances of numbers 0-4.

I want to be able to extract the number of instances a range in column 1 has a 0 next to it. Then a 1, a 2, a 3, and a 4.

For example, how many times 0-29 in column 1 has a 2 next to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842) is for

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&30,B:B,2)
```